# When can two integers of this form be said to belong to the same set?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

If I have two numbers $a_1$ and $a_2$ of the form:

$$ 
a_1=b_1 C+d_1\mod E
$$

and

$$ a_2=b_2 C+d_2\mod E $$

where I know $C$ and $E$ but $b_1$ and $b_2$ are arbitrary positive integers. Under what conditions can I say say that $d_1 \neq d_2$? In other words, when can I say that $a_1$ and $a_2$ belong to the same set of numbers, say, $a_x=x C+d_1\mod E$.

You can think of this process as taking steps of size $C$ in an circular graph of length $E$, starting from, say, node $d_1$. Depending on the value of $C$ you'll touch some nodes and not others. For example, if $C=2$ and $E$ is even, you'll touch all the even or odd nodes depending on whether you start on an even or odd value of $d_1$. On the other hand, walks that start at $d_1$ and $d_2=2d_1$ will be indistinguishable (they'll eventually touch the same set of nodes). Also, if $C=1$ you touch every node so you can't say if $d_1=d_2$ or not.

It's easy to come up with other relatively simple examples, and for any specific set of values of $C$, $E$, $d_1$ and $d_2$ you can generate (in principle) all possible values of $a_1$ and $a_2$, but is there there a general way of answering the question above? In other words, given $a_1$ and $a_2$ can I say that they belong to different walks or not?

I'm a programmer and not a mathematician, but I suspect that it will also depend on whether $C$, $E$, or both are prime numbers or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't too hard to show (with the proper math tools) that, if $C$, $d$, and $E$ are fixed numbers, then the set of all integers that is congruent to something of the form $bC+d$ modulo $E$ is the same as the set of all integers congruent to $d$ modulo $g$, where $g=\gcd(C,E)$.

- Necessity: suppose $a\equiv bC+d\pmod E$. Since $g\mid E$, then in particular $a\equiv bC+d\pmod g$. But $g\mid C$ as well, and so $a\equiv b\cdot0+d = d\pmod g$.
- Sufficiency: suppose $a\equiv d\pmod g$. Rearrange the desired congruence $a\equiv bC+d\pmod E$ as $a-d\equiv bC\pmod E$. Now all terms are divisible by $g$, so we can write $\frac{a-d}g \equiv b\frac Cg \pmod{\frac Eg}$. Finally, the fact that $g=\gcd(C,E)$ means that $\frac Cg$ and $\frac Eg$ are relatively prime, so that $(\frac Cg)^{-1}\pmod{\frac Eg}$ exists; therefore the congruence has the solution $b \equiv (\frac Cg)^{-1} \frac{a-d}g \pmod{\frac Eg}$.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Just to make sure I understand you correctly, you're essentially saying that $a_1$ and $a_2$ correspond to the same value of $d$ if $a_1 (mod g)$ is the same as $a_2 (mod g)$?

Also, I can't say anything about $a_1$ and $a_2$ if both $C$ and $E$ are prime (since then $gcd(C, E)$=1)?

Comment: Yes that's essentially what I'm saying

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful!